# How to sum up specific slices with a 3D Matrix in a loop?

Tags: python, loops

I have a 3D Matrix with slices, rows and columns. It has 720 slices.

I want to sum up the first 20 slices and then the next 20 and so on.

I already have some really unwieldy code.

**Question**

How can I make use of a loop to achieve this?

---

My code so far:

```
# (bin_mask_arrs is already in a for loop. Shape is (720,461,421)
bin_mask_arrs[i]= np.nanmean(bin_mask_arrs[i])

a1 = (np.sum(bin_mask_arrs[:24,1,1]))                                               
a2 = (np.sum(bin_mask_arrs[25:48,1,1]))
a3 = (np.sum(bin_mask_arrs[49:72,1,1]))
# ......
a30 = (np.sum(bin_mask_arrs[697:720,1,1]))

# and then put everything together:

list1 = (a1,a2,a3,.....,a30)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of a1,a2,a3...a30, use a list comprehension like:

```
a = [np.sum(bin_mask_arrs[x*24:(x+1)*24,1,1]) for x in range(30)]
# 'list1' in your code is same as 'a'
```

Moreover, your slices are incorrect, they need to be 0:24, 24:48, 48:72 ... 696:720

Answer (score 0):

As you have written the non-loop code, the solution is pretty straightforward.

```
list1 = [np.sum(bin_mask_arrs[i * 24:i * 24 + 24, 1, 1]) for i in range(30)]
```

Hope that this is what you're asking for